# Where do you put your form definitions in Django?

Tags: django, django-forms

Where are you "supposed" to put form definitions in Django, in `models.py` or in `views.py` and most importantly why?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

form definitions are supposed to go in `forms.py` in the same package, and referenced from there. This is for code modularization.

Comment: Cool. I have never found this in the django docs. I don't feel now bad because it felt funny to me putting them in either models.py or views.py.

Comment: yeah, one of the things you figure out when you see the way some popular third party applications are structured.